# How can I keep element visible when not hovering on fadeIn element any longer?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, toggle, fade

I have an image element that looks like it is inside a parent `div` when it is actually underneath/outside it. I'm currently using JQuery to `fadeIn` the image element when the cursor is hovered over it and fadeout when the cursor moves away. But when I attempt to hover over the now visible image element it disappears. Moving the image element inside parent div isn't an option at the moment.

[Heres the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ST7jp/) demonstrating the issue

How can I prevent it from fading out when I point the cursor on the image element when it becomes visible?

Comment: why you can't move the image inside the div? you can do something like this [http://jsfiddle.net/ST7jp/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/ST7jp/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the link into the `.hover()` selector :

```
$('.container, .link').hover(...);
```

After that, you'll need to use `.stop()` to prevent the queuing :

```
$('.container, .link').hover( function (){
    $('.link').stop().fadeIn();
}, function(){
    $('.link').stop().fadeOut();
});
```

Then you'll have a bug when fast-hovering the `div` because `fadeIn()` only proc when element is hidden so use `fadeTo`:

```
$('.container, .link').hover( function (){
    $('.link').stop().fadeTo('slow', 1);
}, function(){
    $('.link').stop().fadeTo('slow', 0);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ST7jp/4/